# Google Drive SDK 1.8.1 RedirectURL

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Is there any way to provide RedirectURL then using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker?

Here is the sample code in C#:

```
Task<UserCredential> credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes, GoogleDataStore.User, cancellationToken, dataStore);
```

Or we have to use different approach?

I have an "installed application" that runs on a user's desktop, not a website. By default, when I create an "installed application" project in the API console, the redirect URI seems to be set to local host by default.

What ends up happening is that after the authentication sequence the user gets redirected to localhost and receives a browser error. I would like to prevent this from happening by providing my own redirect URI: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto

This seems to be possible using Python version of the Google Client API, but I find it difficult to find any reference to this with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the implementation of [PromptCodeReceiver](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/PromptCodeReceiver.cs), as you can see it contains the redirect uri.

You can implement your own ICodeReceiver with your prefer redirect uri, and call it from a WebBroker which should be similar to [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs?r=e6585033994bfb3a24d4c140db834cb14b9738b2#28).

I think it would be great to understand why can't you just use PrompotCodeReceiver or [LocalServerCodeReceiver](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs).

And be aware that we just released a new library last week, so you should update it to 1.9.0.

UPDATE (more details, Nov 25th 2014):

You can create your own ICodeReceiver. You will have to do the following: 
* The code was never tested... sorry.

```
public class MyNewCodeReceiver : ICodeReceiver
{
    public string RedirectUri
    {
        get { return YOU_REDIRECT_URI; }
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl> ReceiveCodeAsync(
      AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url,
      CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
    {
        // YOUR CODE HERE FOR RECEIVING CODE FROM THE URL.
        // TAKE A LOOK AT THE FOLLOWING:
        // PromptCodeReceiver AND LocalServerCodeReceiver
        // FOR EXAMPLES.
    }
}
```

[PromptCodeReceiver](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/PromptCodeReceiver.cs#38)
and [LocalServerCodeReceiver](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs#76).

Then you will have to do the following
(instead of using the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync method):

```
var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = secrets,
    Scopes = scopes,
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth");
};
await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer),
        new MyNewCodeReceiver())
    .AuthorizeAsync(user, taskCancellationToken);
```

In addition:

1. I'll be happy to understand further why you need to set a different redirect uri, so we will be able to improve the library accordingly.
2. When I create an installed application the current PromptCodeReceiver and LocalServerCodeReceiver work for me, so I'm not sure what's the problem with your code.

Comment: Will be helpful if you can elaborate your answer.  Google .Net APIs suck to a level that I am just giving up dealing with these.  I can't find anyway to pass on my own redirect url. It is possible to do it in python or php apis but not in .net apis. Why?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119038/google-oauth2-redirect-url-issues.  OAuth2 is being used by so many other companies. Never had any issues using their apis. Google apis, documentation, sample code (full of errors) are the worst.

Comment: I updated my answer, be aware that we are working hard to improve the library, so any concrete suggestion will be appreciated. Feel free to open a new issue in our issue tracker explaining what exactly do you need - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list. Remember that the library is open source, so feel free to contribute.

Comment: "I'll be happy to understand further why you need to set a different redirect uri, so we will be able to improve the library accordingly."  -   I don't need to have a different redirect url. I just need to have "a redirect url".  There is no place to put one. Right now the implementation has some localhost/authorize hardcoded (why???). I just don't get it. Why not put a parameter in the existing implementation to allow users to pass a redirect url?

Comment: Look at the current implementation of LocalServerCodeReceiver.  It puts redirect_url to http://localhost:<random port>/authorize.  Can you please explain why this is supposed to work given that Google must find the same url in console settings?

Comment: It's NOT random. It's the one we listening to using the TCP Listener - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs#114.

Comment: I understand, but Google Console doesn't know this url, hence it throws the "mismatched url" error.  Isn't there an implementation for web apps?  Also, AuthorizeAsync method in your above code snippet is throwing AggregateException.  Any pointers?

Comment: In installed application you won't get it, because installed application doesn't check for matching url. It is ONLY web application that checks mismatching urls. From the story mentioned here the question is regarding an installed app and not a web app!

Comment: Oh I see.  What broker do I use for a WebApp?

Comment: Take a look in our documentation - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications for ASP.NET MVC. There is also a sample for ASP.NET in https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2FTasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2.

Comment: I am still trying but so far it has not worked.    Dim result = New AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(userid, CancellationToken.None).Result throws AggregateException and thats it.  It never goes to Google for authentication.

Comment: That exception was solved.  Now one last remaining.  When code is not nothing, I just want to get the token from flow and use that token to create CalendarService object.  Can't seem to find a method on flow to get usercredential or initialiser.  The example code redirects the request when code is not nothing.  Not sure when is the code that creates TasksService object in your code sample invoked?