# Google OAuth2 Redirect URL Issues

Tags: oauth-2.0

I cannot figure out how to pass a redirect url to accomplish OAuth2 authorization.  Google REST API indicates that redirect_url parameters can be passed but this .Net API does not seem to have a feature to pass redirect url

```
Dim Coll As New List(Of String)

Coll.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
Coll.Add(Google.Apis.Tasks.v1.TasksService.Scope.Tasks)

Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With { _
                .ClientId = ClientCredentials.ClientID, _
                .ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret _
                 }, Coll, "user", CancellationToken.None, New SavedDataStore(myStoredResponse)).Result

Dim CalService = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
                .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
                .ApplicationName = "myApp"})
```

A browser instance is launched when this code is executed but the return_url parameter in that request is always to to some random url (e.g., `http://localhost:<random port number>/Authorize`.  Don't know where is this value coming from.  In the API console, I have set `http://localhost:4444/Home/Index`. Since there is no match, authentication throws Error: `redirect_uri_mismatch`

The above code results into this request url

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=589627125301.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:44933/authorize/&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks
```

In summary the question is, where is this `http://localhost:44933/authorize/` coming from?

Any pointers as to how to set this redirect_uri parameter in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a .CallbackURL property. Google API usually looks for one.